# Postman in circleci - Error calling workflow: 'workflow'

Tags: api, postman, circleci, newman

Trying to run simple postman API calls but getting

```
Error calling workflow: 'workflow'
```

My `.circleci/config.yml` is

```
$ cat .circleci/config.yml 
version: 2.1
orbs:
  newman: postman/newman@0.0.2
jobs:
  newman-collection-run:
    executor: newman/postman-newman-docker
    steps:
      - checkout
      - newman/newman-run:
          collection: ./collection.json
```

---

`collection.json` is at the root of the project and is the export from postman.

I am using the example from

https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/postman/newman

which shows:

[image]

The "workflow" reference comes from the original example on the circleci site (not with newman) when I start building on this branch and I've replaced the config file contents in the branch and pushed it so not sure why this reference is coming up ?

Here is that original screen:

[image]

which I change to be:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Do you not need `build:` before the executor step?

Comment: There documentation didn't show that.  I tried adding it, indented by two and then indenting the lines under it by 2 more but I gets long errors in config file, probably from parsing

Comment: I have a repo that I was using to show basic different Newman/CI example, might help but also might not  https://github.com/DannyDainton/postman-ci-pipeline-example/blob/master/README.md#how-does-it-work-with-circleci

Comment: ty @DannyDainton checking it out now

Comment: YES.  That was it. thank you SOOO much

Comment: Please could you post that an answer for me to accept and to help others

Comment: so annoying thei doc doesn't show it, but so gratreful you helped.

Comment: No worries - I hadn't run that for a year...ran it just now and the service I use is down so it fails  which part worked for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the line of the error you left out (see [the build](https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/durrantm/BD-TD-API-POSTMAN/13/workflows/96b82523-1384-4c2a-b0c8-6a3aacc88c12/jobs/25/steps)), you can see *why* there's an error calling the workflow:

```
# Error calling workflow: 'workflow'
# Cannot find a definition for job named build
```

This requirement is documented [in the config file reference](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#jobs) (emphasis mine):

> If you are not using workflows, the `jobs` map **must contain a job
>   named `build`**. This `build` job is the default entry-point for a run
>   that is triggered by a push to your VCS provider. It is possible to
>   then specify additional jobs and run them using the CircleCI API.

But why is it looking for a job named build in a workflow named workflow? Because if you don't supply a workflow explicitly, CircleCI uses the following default:

```yaml
workflows:
  version: 2
  workflow:
    jobs:
    - build
```

You can see this by using [CircleCI's Local CLI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/) to run `circleci config process .circleci/config.yml` on the fixed version in [Danny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62119780/3001761).

This suggests another solution to the problem; rather than renaming the job, **supply the workflow**:

```yaml
version: 2.1
orbs:
  newman: postman/newman@0.0.2
jobs:
  newman-collection-run:
    executor: newman/postman-newman-docker
    steps:
      - checkout
      - newman/newman-run:
          collection: ./collection.json
workflows:
  version: 2
  workflow:
    jobs:
    - newman-collection-run
```

---

As a side note, while looking to see if I could figure what message you saw on the original failing build, this is what I was met with:

```
* 37737f0 - (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) config (22 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
* e04efa0 - config (22 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
*   e640e4e - merge into master (26 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
|\
| * cc16160 - config (27 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 13e0ad5 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * e4df02c - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * b287102 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 14bd61c - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 0f81d84 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * ccd06b6 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 2b909f3 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 4b15bca - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 240c591 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 50096a9 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * ad9fe60 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 7c19205 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 3c0a3b9 - config (28 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 2d1954e - config (29 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 4e1f087 - config (29 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 9413b68 - config (29 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 942d493 - config (29 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * e8412b8 - config (29 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * c136702 - Add .circleci/config.yml (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 2203710 - Add .circleci/config.yml (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 94a084e - Add .circleci/config.yml (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * ec40356 - Add .circleci/config.yml (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
| * 6964057 - Add .circleci/config.yml (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
* | 4e5c9d1 - coinfig (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
* | cbf49fd - workflow name (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
* | 6245ae1 - workflow name (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
* | fdf52b5 - workflow name (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
* | 0c4c455 - workflow name (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
|/
* 7c31fb6 - update circleci config (30 hours ago) <Michael Durrant>
```

This isn't a healthy way to work with git; if you're not going to give your future self enough context to understand what is changing, I would recommending squashing out all the redundant commits when you bring the changes into master.

Note you can get the error messages for basic config file failures locally with the CLI by running `circleci config validate`, which saves the loop of pushing all of those commits that can't work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the original `config.yml` file is missing the `build:` step, which comes in before the `executor:` line.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  newman: postman/newman@0.0.2
jobs:
  build:
    executor: newman/postman-newman-docker
    steps:
      - checkout
      - newman/newman-run:
          collection: ./collection.json
```

Comment: Danny I upvoted yours, accepted Jon's (more complete) but in compensation (for you being first and helping me quickest) I've checked out a couple of your other good postman answers and upvoted 2 of them :)

Comment: You got the answer you needed so I'm happy that you're happy 